# Existence of a matrix that satisfies certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $\mathscr{M}$ be the set of all $m\times n$ real matrices. Endow $\mathscr{M}$ with the usual operator norm: $$\|A\|=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{|Ax|}{|x|},$$ where $|\cdot|$ is just the Euclidean norm in the relevant space. Assume $\mathscr{W}\subset\mathscr{M}$ is a convex subset whose interior is nonempty. Convexity is defined in the usual sense, i.e. if $A,B\in\mathscr{W}$, then $\alpha A+(1-\alpha)B\in\mathscr{W}$ where $\alpha A$ is just the usual scalar multiplication.

Fix $A\in \mathrm{int}W$. Let $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ be two scalars such that $0<\gamma<\gamma'<1$. Fix also a positive scalar $\epsilon>0$. Does there exists a matrix $B\in \mathscr{W}$ such that the following hold:

1. $A-\frac{1-\gamma'}{1-\gamma}B$ is a matrix, each row of which is a constant;
2. $\|A-B\|\leq \epsilon$;
3. $\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma'-\gamma}\big[A-\frac{1-\gamma'}{1-\gamma}B\big]\in\mathscr{W}$.

For example if $A$ is a matrix with constant rows, i.e. $a_{ij}=a_{ik}$ for all $i,j,k$, then the matrix $A$ satisfies the above three requirements. The question is that if $A$ does not have constant rows, then can we perturb $A$ a little bit so that it has constant rows.

Thanks